# Can Mysql IN() function be used to Match ALL of its values instead of ANY?

Tags: php, mysql

**My question:**
Can Mysql IN() function be used to Match ALL the values passed to it instead of ANY? If it cannot, is there another function that can do so?

**See an example of what I am running into:**

```
$catIds = implode(',' array(8, 15));
$q = "SELECT account_id 
      FROM category_records
      WHERE user_id = '5'
      AND category_id IN ($catIds) ";
$r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $q);
```

**Table Architecture:**

```
id  |  user_id  |  category_id  |  account_id
1   |  5        |  8            |  150
2   |  5        |  12           |  150
3   |  5        |  15           |  150
4   |  5        |  8            |  153
5   |  5        |  15           |  153
6   |  5        |  12           |  160
7   |  5        |  3            |  160
8   |  5        |  15           |  165
9   |  5        |  8            |  165

$catArray = ('8', '15');
```

In above rows Account #150 & #165 should be returned since both are in Category 8 and 15.

Comment: what is in `$catArray` ?

Comment: NO it is not possible with IN() .. you need to todo it with AND instead of IN()

Comment: Also you can glue the array together more easily with `implode(', ',  $catArray);`
Saves you a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it actually be possible for a column to match ALL the values?

If I understand correctly, you have a table similar to the following:

```
| id  | use_id  | category_id  |
|-----|---------|--------------|
| 1   |    1    |      3       |
| 2   |    5    |      1       |
| 3   |    12   |      4       |
| 4   |    9    |      4       |
| 5   |    15   |      1       |
```

So, each row can only ever be equal to one item on the array. If that is the case then IN is your answer. Answers describing the use of AND operand instead will not work here since one category_id cannot match against 3 or 4 ids.

The answer could be different if 'category_id' column contains multiple Ids per row (which would not be very good design).

**-- EDIT --**

Given the table information, I think I understand what you need. You need to select rows whose category_id is in 8 and 15 AND have the same account_id. In that case, try the code with the following query:

```
$catIds = implode(',' $catArray);
$q =      "SELECT cr.* FROM category_records cr " 
        . "INNER JOIN ( "
        . "SELECT account_id FROM category_records "
        . "     WHERE category_id in (". catIds . ") "
        . "     GROUP BY account_id HAVING count(account_id ) > 1 "
        . " ) dup "
        . "ON   cr.account_id = dup.account_id "
        . "WHERE"
        . " cr.category_id in (". catIds . ") "
        . "AND"
        . " cr.user_id = ". $this->user_id;
$r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $q);
```

Comment: Killneel - that did it. You successfully returned the accounts that contain ALL of the selected array values. Great work, and thanks for the help.